# Windows UWP - How to wrap GridView inside a HubSection

Tags: c#, windows, data-binding, win-universal-app

I have an example of a working `GridView` and can't seem to have any luck moving it to work inside a `HubSection`. My real app needs to do this and this example is my mule to understand how the databinding needs to work.

The `HubSection` complains that it can't have a `GridView` as a child.

My current model code looks like this:

```
namespace Quickstart {
  public class Recording {
    public string ArtistName { get; set; }
    public string CompositionName { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDateTime { get; set; }
    public Uri ImageUri { get; set; }

    public Recording(string name, string composition, DateTime when, string prefixedFilename)
    {
        this.ArtistName = name;
        this.CompositionName = composition;
        this.ReleaseDateTime = when;
     //   string prefixedFilename = "ms-appx://Quickstart/Assets/" + filename;
        ImageUri = new Uri(prefixedFilename);
    }

    public string OneLineSummary {
        get
        {
            return $"{this.CompositionName} by {this.ArtistName}, released: "
                + this.ReleaseDateTime.ToString("d");
        }
    }
  }

  public class RecordingViewModel {
    List<Recording> recordings;

    public RecordingViewModel()
    {
        recordings = new List<Quickstart.Recording>();
        recordings.Add(new Recording("Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart", "Andante in C for Piano", new DateTime(1761, 1, 1), "http://csimg.koopkeus.nl/srv/NL/29023839m56849/T/340x340/C/FFFFFF/url/mozart.jpg"));
        recordings.Add(new Recording("Nickleback", "Gotta be Somebody", new DateTime(2003, 8, 21), "http://images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/16500000/n-nickelback-16579001-634-634.jpg"));
    }

    public List<Recording> RecordingList { get { return this.recordings; } }
  }

}
```

and the xaml:

```
<Page
x:Class="Quickstart.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Quickstart"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind recordings}" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" x:Name="RecordingGrid">
  <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Recording">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="{Binding ImageUri, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="100" Opacity="1" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ArtistName}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind CompositionName}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ReleaseDateTime}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
  </GridView>
</Page>
```

finally the xaml.cs:

```
namespace Quickstart {
  public sealed partial class MainPage : Page {
    List<Recording> recordings;
    public MainPage() {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        recordings = new RecordingViewModel().RecordingList;
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, it's about as simple as it gets! Thanks for you time!

Comment: What exactly is the problem? I don't even see a HubSection in your code.

Comment: please post the code with the hub section. You also need to put the `GridView`in a `Grid` within the `HubSection`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The HubSection complains that it can't have a GridView as a child.

For this problem, you can refer to [HubSection class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.HubSection);k(VS.XamlEditor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0)&rd=true). For a hub section, we don't add content directly to it, we define the content of the `HubSection` in a `DataTemplate`.

So for your problem, you can do it like this:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:RecordingViewModel x:Name="vm" />
</Page.DataContext>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Hub>
        <HubSection x:Name="section1" Width="600">
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding recordings}"  Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" x:Name="RecordingGrid">
                        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageUri, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="100" Opacity="1" Stretch="Uniform" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ArtistName}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CompositionName}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ReleaseDateTime}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    </GridView>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
    </Hub>
</Grid>
```

When you do this(adding the DataContext in Xaml), there is no need to add any code in the MainPage.cs file:

```
//private List<Recording> recordings;

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    //recordings = new RecordingViewModel().RecordingList;
}
```

And you will need to change your `RecordingViewModel` class like this:

```
public class RecordingViewModel
{
    public List<Recording> recordings
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public RecordingViewModel()
    {
        recordings = new List<Recording>();
        recordings.Add(new Recording("Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart", "Andante in C for Piano", new DateTime(1761, 1, 1), "http://csimg.koopkeus.nl/srv/NL/29023839m56849/T/340x340/C/FFFFFF/url/mozart.jpg"));
        recordings.Add(new Recording("Nickleback", "Gotta be Somebody", new DateTime(2003, 8, 21), "http://images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/16500000/n-nickelback-16579001-634-634.jpg"));
    }

    public List<Recording> RecordingList { get { return this.recordings; } }
}
```

As you know, if you want to use {x:Bind} in a `DataTemplate`, you should define the `x:DataType` for binding, because the value of the Path of {x:Bind} is not interpreted in the context of the page, but in the context of the data object being templated.

As we can see here, the `GridView` is inside a `DataTemplate` already, since there is only a datacontext(your RecordingViewModel), but no data model for this `DataTemplate`, we can not use {x:Bind} here for the `ItemSource` of `GridView` inside of it. But we can use {x:Bind} for the controls inside the `DataTemplate` of the `GridView`, for example like this:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Recording" x:Key="recordingitem">
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Source="{Binding ImageUri, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="100" Opacity="1" Stretch="Uniform" />
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ArtistName}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind CompositionName}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ReleaseDateTime}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:RecordingViewModel x:Name="vm" />
</Page.DataContext>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Hub>
        <HubSection x:Name="section1" Width="600">
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding recordings}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource recordingitem}"  Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" x:Name="RecordingGrid">
                    </GridView>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
    </Hub>
</Grid>
```

And the code behind is the same as {Binding} method in the upper.

Comment: Thank you very much @Grace Feng for the comprehensive and useful answer!